# Batch File - Copying over directories with spaces

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**The Goal**

I want to:

1 - Loop over directories on a remote network and create a directory (if it doesn't exist) locally

2 - Within the sub-directory on the remote file, copy the files to the directory of the same name on the local folder, then delete the source file on the remote directory.

3 - At some point set this up to run daily via Window Scheduler

**The Problem**
My code (see below) does everything I want it to do EXCEPT if a subdir has a space in them, it'll loop over every word and create a new folder for it. Ex. if there a folder called 'Docs and Notes', it'll create folders for:

```
- Docs and Notes
- Docs
- and
- Notes
```

**What I have so far**

```
FOR /R "Z:\REMOTE_DIR" %%F IN (.) DO (
  Pushd %%F

  if exist C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF\NUL echo "Folder already exists"
  if not exist C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF\NUL mkdir C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF

  cd C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF
  FOR %%G IN (.) DO (
    robocopy %%G C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF /MOV /s /xn
  ) 

  Popd
)
```

Any thoughts on how to prevent this? Thank you!

Comment: Sure you should try `if not exist C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF\NUL mkdir "C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF"` and `robocopy "%%~G" "C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL\%%~nxF" /MOV /s /xn` just like that for those lines. Let me know if that helps resolve.

Comment: Put quotation marks around every path and replace `cd` by `cd /D`...

Comment: the `for /r` will grab every sub folder at every level of your remote directory - is it intended to make a new folder for each of those in your local directory? why not just `robocopy "Z:\REMOTE_DIR" "C:\Users\Jane.Doe\LOCAL" /mov /s /xn`?